# Using property decorator to set and get object values in Python

Tags: python, properties, attributes, decorator, python-decorators

I want to use the property decorator to assign values to an attribute of an object.

```
class Response:

    _result = {}

    @property
    def result(self):
        print 'getter'
        return self._result

    @result.setter
    def result(self, obj):
        print 'setter'
        self._result.update(obj)

    @result.deleter
    def result(self):
        print 'deleter'
        self._result = {}


r = Response()

r.result = {'test':123}

print r.result
```

I must be doing something wrong, because the output is:

> {'test': 123}

Why are the print statements not executed?
What I expect to see is:

> setter
>
> getter
>
> {'test': 123}